# Circle with 2 centres

Tags: geometry, circles

> [image: A circle with two centers]
>
> At points $B$ and $C$ of an $\measuredangle{BAC}$ erect perpendiculars and let them intersect in $D$. Since $AB$ and $AC$ are not parallel, the perpendiculars are not parallel either. Thus, unless $AB$ and $AC$ form a $0°$ or a $180°$ angle, point $D$ is well defined.
>
> Draw a circle circumscribing $ΔBCD$. Besides $B$, the circle intersects $AB$ in another point, say, $E$. It intersects $AC$ in $F$ different from $C$. Now, since $∠DBE$ is right, $DE$ is a diameter of the circle. The midpoint of $DE$ is the center of the circle. A similar argument applies to $DF$. As a result, we arrive at the conclusion that the circle at hand has two centers.

**How can this be possible ?**

**What is the mistake in this explanation ?**

I tried to do this problem for one full day but I still cannot solve this. How can it be possible for a circle to have 2 centers ?

Answer (score 5):

By the given construction, the circumscribed circle goes through $A$ ($AD$ is a diameter), so that $A=E=F$ and planet Earth is safe.

Comment: Took me a second to spot, but yes, this is the answer. A quadrilateral is cyclic (i.e. all corners lie on one circle) iff opposite corners have an angle sum of $180^\circ$, which is the case here (it doesn't matter which pair of opposite corners you choose). The moral to the story is: never trust figures blindly.

Comment: The previous comment should be included in the answer :)

Comment: @Arthur great work

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes the planet Earth is safe